# A simple matrix multiplication for big matrices in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix-multiplication

Given two very big matrices in MATLAB, how can I multiply them in fast manner? The multiplication should be a matrix multiplication (not bitwise) therefore it seem using a function like `bsxfun` is NOT possible.

**Example:**

```
 A = rand(100000,50000) ;
 B = rand(50000,50000)  ;
 C = A* B %% takes too much time
```

DO you have any ideas?

Comment: That is the fastest you will ever get it.  Native MATLAB matrix multiplication uses a modification of FORTRAN's LAPACK under the hood, which is already fast as it is after many years of research and optimization.  There's a reason why the libraries are still used in FORTRAN, and this is it.  There's also a reason why MATLAB is used for matrix manipulation, and this is it.

Comment: If you have some special structure on the matrices (symmetric, sparse, etc.) then there are options.  For random matrices, @rayryeng spelled it out perfectly.

Comment: Better hardware is also an option, especially if this is something you need to do often, or for a commercial or research purpose.

Comment: Thanks alot for the supporting information